# Bind Data to Telerik Grid using AJAX Response

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using Telerik Grid Control.

Procedure:

I will select any one of the table name from combobox and in onchange event of this combobox i am doing ajax request and now i want to bind the data to Telerik Grid using Ajax response.

Every thing working fine except, this binding data to grid using this Ajax response..

Can any gudie me regading this....

Answer (score 1):

On Change event of the combobox ,get the 'tGrid' using the grid id and set the datasource using the DataBind()

```
$('#comboboxId').change(  function () {
    var grid = $("#theGrid").data("tGrid");
    var url= 'http://yourUrlGoesHere?Type=' + $('#comboboxId').val()
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {grid.dataBind(data);});


    });
```